# How to consume Shopify webhooks in Python

Tags: python-3.x, shopify, webhooks

I am trying to get my head around webhooks. I receive a webhook from Shopify. I used [Beeceptor](https://beeceptor.com/) to receive the web hook which looks like the screenshot attached. It is a JSON. I want to use Python to process the received POST and take some action.

Q: Can I know how I can retrieve this JSON in my Python code? Do I need to use the Flask framework or can I do it with a request? Here are details from Shopify https://shopify.dev/tutorials/manage-webhooks#verify-webhook which I am unsure of.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a web app that can accept incoming HTTP traffic from Shopify - you can do this in Flask/Python or really any other web technology stack. Services like AWS Lambda can also work to receive the webhook and do some processing.

However, to ease the development and testing you need to do the following steps.

1. Webhook configuration and Payload discovery. That means you need to know all types of events coming from Shopify.
2. Write the code to consume these payloads.
3. Do the dev/integration testing.

You can use the Local Tunnel (Port Forwarding) concept to expose the Python service running locally to the internet and then use the public-facing URL as a Webhook endpoint in Shopify. This is a niche way for webhook integration testing where event payloads from Shopify will be directly routed to the service running on your laptop.

(For the tool you picked, it appears to have local tunnel support. https://beeceptor.com/local-tunnel/ )

Comment: Thanks. Is it not possible without any web app framework in Python?Would this not be like fetching from API?

Comment: A webhook is like a reverse API - you don't call or fetch from it, but instead it calls your web service that needs to handle the call. Whether you use a framework, or some service like I mentioned is up to you, but ultimately you must have a running web app somewhere.